# Display the names of each employees who works in both ‘IT’ and ‘SE’

Tags: sql, rdbms

Emp(sid(pk) : integer, sname: varchar(255))
Dep(sid(fk) : integer, dep : varchar(255))

SQL:How I find the names of each employees who works in both ‘IT’ and ‘SE’?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

> *To observe a query that `Joins` two tables together and get common values depend on a common column **Ex**: `id`, using `INNTER JOIN` will help you on that*

> > ***The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.***

[image: SQL INNER JOIN Keyword]

#### Solution

```sql
 SELECT Emp.sid, Emp.sname FROM Emp
 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT sid FROM Dep WHERE dep='IT'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT sid FROM Dep WHERE dep='SE') as A
    ON Emp.sid = A.sid
```

#### References

[SQL INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, the data situation is as below. `emp` with `sid` and `sname`, and `dep`, with `sid` - the foreign key to `emp` and `dep`, this time not as a table, but a column containing the department's abbreviation. And the combination, in the `dep` table, of `sid` and `dep`, is unique.

If that is the constellation, then join the two tables using `sid`, filter by: `dep` in the set:(`'IT'` , `'SE'`); Then, put the two columns from `emp` into the the column list, and `GROUP BY` them, and finally, apply the grouping filter `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` to just get the group that has two entries when filtered by the two departments.

```
WITH 
emp(sid, sname) AS (
            SELECT 42,'Arthur'
  UNION ALL SELECT 43,'Ford'
  UNION ALL SELECT 44,'Zaphod'
)
,
dep(sid, dep) AS (
            SELECT 42,'IT'
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'SE'
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'AC'
  UNION ALL SELECT 43,'IT'
  UNION ALL SELECT 43,'AC'
  UNION ALL SELECT 44,'SE'
  UNION ALL SELECT 44,'SA'
)
SELECT
  emp.sid
, emp.sname
FROM emp JOIN dep USING(sid)
WHERE dep.dep IN ('IT','SE')
GROUP BY
  emp.sid
, emp.sname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
-- out sid|sname
-- out  42|Arthur
```